# Making XIB freeform view fit the Superview in Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout, xib

**[subview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmU7h.png)**

I'm currently stuck at making this freeform view follow AutoLayout/TraitVariation adjustments, so that it would look the same on every device. The view is contained in a separate .xib file. Somehow, pin and align tools are disabled. How can I refer to Main.storyboard. I wanna know if there's a way of making it follow superview (Main.storyboard) size using Interface builder.

Comment: Rather easy to do in code, not so much with Interface Builder. Typically I design the two in their respective Xib/Storyboard files, make sure they each behave as intended individually, then I use code to instantiate one into the other.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same thing a couple of weeks ago and unfortunately, it seems there is no solution for that. I ended up with coping my XIB view into storyboard :(